# Moving total which uses two calculated fields and also uses its previous value-Spotfire

Tags: spotfire, cumulative-sum

Hi folks I am new to Spotfire and having difficulty in replicating one of the formulas from Excel to spotfire.

Sample Data
[Sample data here(excel)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyqYr.jpg)
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KSdrIYKlRYG9c3wIM3NwQcLP_Ob8Z2UZ5Cjrdjy8UO8/edit?usp=sharing
and I am trying to replicate the column [Steady Repay-Option Scenario]

[image]

Formula used in excel
       =IF(B6-IF(C3>0,C2,0)>0,B6-IF(C3>0,C2,0),0)

the above is the formula I have in excel where subsequent columns are calculated by using the previous value and the current values from columns [Monthly impact on cash] and  [running total]

This is the formula I have created in spotfire:

```
if((Sum([Scenario opening balance]) over (allPrevious([Document_Date_Number])) - (If(Sum([Rolling_total_cash_calculated]) over (AllPrevious([Document_Date_Number]))>0,Sum([Monthly_impact_on_cash_calculated]) over (AllPrevious([Document_Date_Number])),0)))>0,Sum([Scenario opening balance]) over (allPrevious([Document_Date_Number])) - (If(sum([Rolling_total_cash_calculated]) over (allPrevious([Document_Date_Number]))>0,Sum([Monthly_impact_on_cash_calculated]) OVER (allPrevious([Document_Date_Number])),0)),0)

   Assumptions--
  Data has been pivoted into three columns([Document_Date_Number], Monthly_impact_on_cash_calculated] and [Rolling_total_cash_calculated])
  where:
  [Scenario opening balance] = 150000000(fixed)
  [Document_Date_Number] = Jan,Feb,Mar etc
  [Rolling_total_cash_calculated] = Rolling total(excel)
  [Monthly_impact_on_cash_calculated] = Monthly impact on  cash(excel)
```

But I get incorrect results for some reason

[results in spotfire](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qd9oj.jpg)

[image]

But the expected result is

[Correct result in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuQkO.jpg)

[image]

So although the results match till Oct as shown above they don't seem to match afterwards.

Please let me know what can I do to get the same values. Any help in deeply appreciated.

Comment: Looks like Spotfire result screenshot is missing.

Comment: sample data and expected output is necessary here.

Comment: Thanks ksp575 and Scsimon for your reply, I have now added the sample data. Thanks

Comment: @Shaktirajjena- Could you explain expected result in a table (excel should be fine) as it is very difficult to understand from the screenshots?

Comment: Thanks ksp575. I have shared the placed the excel document here with sample data and the formula used in excel. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KSdrIYKlRYG9c3wIM3NwQcLP_Ob8Z2UZ5Cjrdjy8UO8/edit?usp=sharing